# Looking for the suffix tree implementation in C#?

Tags: c#, data-structures, suffix-tree

I've implemented a basic search for a research project. I'm trying to make the search more efficient by building a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree). I'm interested in a C# implementation of the [Ukkonen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukkonen%27s_algorithm) algorith. I don't want to waste time rolling my own if such implementation exists.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question at all?

Comment: I am trying to implement a search within a research project. I've implemented the reverse index and incremental population of the index. Next I was looking to make the search even more efficient but did not want to roll my own ST implementation if one exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hei, just finished implementing .NET (c#) library containing different trie implementations. Among them:

- Classical trie
- Patricia trie
- Suffix trie
- A trie using **Ukkonen's** algorithm

I tried to make source code easy readable. Usage is also very straight forward:

```
using Gma.DataStructures.StringSearch;

...

var trie = new UkkonenTrie<int>(3);
//var trie = new SuffixTrie<int>(3);

trie.Add("hello", 1);
trie.Add("world", 2);
trie.Add("hell", 3);

var result = trie.Retrieve("hel");
```

The library is well tested and also published as [TrieNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TrieNet/) NuGet package.

See [github.com/gmamaladze/trienet](https://github.com/gmamaladze/trienet)

Comment: Thank you for the Ukkonen's algorithm implementation. Great work.

Answer (score 12):

Hard question.  Here's the closest to match I could find: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ahocorasick.aspx, which is an implementation of the Aho-Corasick string matching algorithm.  Now, the algorithm uses a suffix-tree-like structure per: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho-Corasick_algorithm

Now, if you want a prefix tree, this article claims to have an implementation for you: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/prefixtree.aspx

<*HUMOR*> Now that I did your homework, how about you mow my lawn.  (Reference: http://flyingmoose.org/tolksarc/homework.htm) <*/HUMOR*>

*Edit*: I found a C# suffix tree implementation that was a port of a C++ one posted on a blog:  http://code.google.com/p/csharsuffixtree/source/browse/#svn/trunk/suffixtree

*Edit*: There is a new project at Codeplex that is focused on suffix trees: http://suffixtree.codeplex.com/

Comment: I'm looking for the suffix tree.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation of a suffix tree that is reasonably efficient. I haven't studied Ukkonen's implementation, but the running time of this algorithm I believe is quite reasonable, approximately `O(N Log N)`. Note the number of internal nodes in the tree created is equal to the number of letters in the parent string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace FunStuff
{
    public class SuffixTree
    {
        public class Node
        {
            public int Index = -1;
            public Dictionary<char, Node> Children = new Dictionary<char, Node>();
        }

        public Node Root = new Node();
        public String Text;

        public void InsertSuffix(string s, int from)
        {             
            var cur = Root;
            for (int i = from; i < s.Length; ++i)
            {
                var c = s[i];
                if (!cur.Children.ContainsKey(c))
                {
                    var n = new Node() {Index = from};
                    cur.Children.Add(c, n);

                    // Very slow assertion. 
                    Debug.Assert(Find(s.Substring(from)).Any());

                    return;
                }
                cur = cur.Children[c];
            }
            Debug.Assert(false, "It should never be possible to arrive at this case");
            throw new Exception("Suffix tree corruption");
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Node> VisitTree(Node n)
        {
            foreach (var n1 in n.Children.Values)
                foreach (var n2 in VisitTree(n1))
                    yield return n2;
            yield return n;
        }

        public IEnumerable<int> Find(string s)
        {
            var n = FindNode(s);
            if (n == null) yield break;
            foreach (var n2 in VisitTree(n))
                yield return n2.Index;
        }

        private Node FindNode(string s)
        {
            var cur = Root;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i)
            {
                var c = s[i];
                if (!cur.Children.ContainsKey(c))
                {
                    // We are at a leaf-node.
                    // What we do here is check to see if the rest of the string is at this location. 
                    for (var j=i; j < s.Length; ++j)
                        if (cur.Index + j >= Text.Length || Text[cur.Index + j] != s[j])
                            return null;
                    return cur;
                }
                cur = cur.Children[c];
            }
            return cur;
        }

        public SuffixTree(string s)
        {
            Text = s;
            for (var i = s.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
                InsertSuffix(s, i);
            Debug.Assert(VisitTree(Root).Count() - 1 == s.Length);
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestSuffixTree
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestBasics()
        {
            var s = "banana";
            var t = new SuffixTree(s);
            var results = t.Find("an").ToArray();
            Assert.AreEqual(2, results.Length);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, results[0]);
            Assert.AreEqual(3, results[1]);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: -@cdiggins, sorry for my ignorance. It is my first time to see a class within another class. In your code,`public class Node` is within `public class SuffixTree`, what is the skill herein?

Comment: I know this post is old but there seems to be an issue with this code under some circuimstances that I cant seem to figure. Set S = "TAGGAAATTC" and try t.Find("CTATT") and the line f (Text[cur.Index + j] != s[j]) will result in IndexOutsideBoundsOfArray exception. Your implementation seems to be very elegant and efficient enough (typing out Ukkoken is a bit.. difficult). I can't seem to find a way around this bug.

Comment: @Ilhan I just made a change that should fix the bug.

Comment: Search doesn't work properly in this implementation for cases, when there are 2 matches.